# How to point Subdomain to Nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js

I have the domain and subdomain in GoDaddy and I need to point a subdomain to nodejs server that hosted in AWS lightsail. For example, I have api.domain.com to 12.345.67.890:3100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with exposing the port, simply make an A record and point it to the IP.

If you don't want to expose the port, you need to put a reverse proxy in front of your server, for example, Nginx or HAProxy.

Here's a tutorial on how to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for your Node.js app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oykl1Ih9pMg

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DNS servers?
You should point the DNS servers to your NODEJS server
Take a look in the GoDaddy panel to edit the DNS Server

Here an exemple to help :
https://support.rocketspark.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010277387-How-to-change-your-DNS-settings-in-GoDaddy

Comment: Thank you h4phaistos. I am still confused by where I will add the Port number in DNS manager.